# How use 'slice' function in react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, slice

I was trying to *`slice`* first 5 characters from a string in my react app. but getting following error saying:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined`
**I am using functional component**

```
import React from "react";
function index() {
  const str = "Hello123";
  const strchk = str.slice(0, 5);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{strchk}</h1>
    </>
  );
}

export default index;
```

Comment: In the above code, you are using the String.prototype.slice() function correctly and that should not throw you an error. Can you please share more of your application code, it is possible that the value of str is set to undefined at some point.

Comment: @Link I have add the full code

Comment: The error is from the typo on str

Comment: const str = "Hello123" not    const str = ""Hello123

Comment: That code will not give the error described. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: it was typo sorry, but main problem is i can't use "slice" :(

Comment: @Robbi — In the code you’ve provided, you **can** use slice. There will. Be no error. (In your actual code I’m guessing `str` Isn’t a hard coded string, and that the problem is how you are setting it, but you haven’t shown us that code, you’ve shown us code that *doesn’t have a problem*!)

Comment: @Quentin am noob am just learning and this is my code :)

Comment: The error says that you can’t call `slice` of `undefined`. There is **no possible way** that `str` can be `undefined` in the code you’ve provided.

Comment: I think you have a problem with JS environment because it's work https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-lake-w4xbp

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of slice is correct and the provided example should work.

I would assume that you experience this error in a situation where the object you are calling ".slice(...)" on, does not exist.
Please try to verify that your string object is valid.

Answer (score -1):

You have done typo error. In forth line instead of `const str = ""Hello123;` use `const str = "Hello123";`

How to identify?
since your error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined`
You can see that slice is not getting a valid string. So, in your case that is str which has that typo error due to which this is throwing error.

Comment: While this is an error, it can’t possibly cause the problem described because the code will throw an exception (unexpected identifier)) on the invalid string syntax.